# Intersection of the powers of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and $I\subset A$ an ideal. Prove that $$\cap_{n}{I^n}=(0)\Rightarrow\forall a\in I, a+1\notin D(A)$$
I tried proving that if the thesis is false I get an absurd, but I didn't find anything interesting. Can I have a help?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that $D(A)$ denotes the set of zero divisor. Let $a\in I$ and let $b\in A$ such that $(1+a)b=0$, i.e. $ab=-b$. Multiplying by $a$ yields $a^2b=-ab=b$. Continuing this process we see that $I^n \ni ba^{n}=...$, for arbitrary $n$, and thus $b=...$?

Comment: I think I have to go to bed... I spent the last hour thinking D(A) denotes the units of A...

Comment: @Eigenvalue Have a good night.

Comment: @Eigenvalue usually the set units of $A$ is denoted by $U(A)$ or $A^{\times}$. Moreover, the set of zero divisors is denoted (though this is not standar) by $ZD(A)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already know that. Simply, I don't know what the hell I was thinking :/